# Ajax webshop first displays html page without css for 500 ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm building an ajax online webshop. Everything is going well but I have one annoying problem. Every time I direct to a page where I use ajax (so javascript repeatedly) I first get a html page without css. Just the h1, H2, p tags..

I searched for it but can't find anything.. Here is my code for my product page:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Melkerhei</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="bootstrap/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

<html lang="en">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="adminLvl" style="display: none;">false</div>
    <body onload="var k1=window.setTimeout('getCurrentUser(\'get\');', 0); var k2=window.setTimeout('getStock();', 100);">
     <div id=navbar></div>  
         <div class="container" >
        <h1>Products</h1>
          <div id="row" class="row" >   

             </div>
               <div id="cart" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" style="width:400px; float:right; margin-left:0; display: none;">
               <h3>Shopping cart</h3>
               <table id="cartTable" class="table table-bordered">
                  <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Aantal producten</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Totale prijs</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td id="amount" style="text-align: center">0</td>
                     <td id="price" style="text-align: center">0</td>
                   </tr>
              </table>
              <button onclick="location.href='shoppingcart.html';" id="myButton"  class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:50px;">Meer details!</button>
            </div>
         <div id="footer"  style="clear:both;"></div>
     </div> 

     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript ================================================== -->

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/user.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/stock.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/search.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/shop.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/logout.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
       $("#header").load("header.html"); 
       $("#navbar").load("navbarsearch.html"); 
       $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function setName() {
        var user = document.getElementById("currentUser");
        document.getElementById("userLabel").value =     user.childNodes[0].textContent;            
    }
    </script> 
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I don't believe the problem is to do with CSS loading but instead to do with the page layout content which you load via AJAX. You should really use server side includes to load your `header.html`, `navbarsearch.html` and `footer.html` pages. It will avoid this FOUC problem completely.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : thx for your help, you got any suggestions how to implement that?

Comment: It depends on what your server supports. Google for 'Server side include [language]'

Comment: When I do things like "<div id="navbar"></div>" in my html code so i can use the page for admin, users and guests he also loads it first without and than with.. any answer? :s

Comment: Serverside would be something like PHP or C# Razor as Rory suggested. 
I think it is with Bootstrap.  You need that in the head.  The issue is that Bootstrap relies on implementing a 'Theme'.  Bootstrap JS triggers the CSS classes to load on the elements and applies the theme that way.  That is why the HTML elements are loading unstyled first, THEN the Bootstrap JS loads and then applies the CSS to the elements.  I would put Bootstrap up top with the CSS in the head.